# How to run a scheduled class that is not running in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have scheduled a class in salesforce to run everyday at 6 am but it doesnot run.
The problem is that it gets queued everyday and finally gets aborted .What possibly could be the reason for this? Could you suggest me a solution ?
Can we have priority to run a scheduled class.

Scheduling code:

```
   global with sharing class Sample implements Schedulable{
      global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
      List<Sample_object__c> allRecurringSubsList = new List<Sample_object__c>(); 
     Job_Log__c JobStatus=new Job_Log__c(); 
     subscriptions allRecurringSubsList = [Select Id,Zuora__SubscriptionEndDate__c,Zuora__AutoRenew__c from Sample_object__c where Days_To_Expiration__c in (0,1,30,60,90)]; 

   if(!allRecurringSubsList.isEmpty()){
    update allRecurringSubsList ;
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: global with sharing class Sample implements Schedulable{

global void execute(SchedulableContext  SC){
 
    List<Sample_object__c> allRecurringSubsList = new List<Sample_object__c>();
    Job_Log__c JobStatus=new Job_Log__c();      subscriptions
        allRecurringSubsList = [Select Id,Zuora__SubscriptionEndDate__c,Zuora__AutoRenew__c from Sample_object__c 
                                where Days_To_Expiration__c in (0,1,30,60,90)];
        
        if(!allRecurringSubsList.isEmpty()){
            update allRecurringSubsList ;
           
        }
} 
}

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions? Usually when a class stays in queue it means there's some sort of exception or missing permissions.

Comment: No problem with permissions and exception ...it used to run earlier bt now its queued